# VBA to update hyperlinks in PPT

Tags: excel, vba, path, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have a PPT file that contains 5 hyperlinks on the third slide. These are the only hyperlinks in the PPT. Each hyperlink references the SAME Excel File, just a different sheet within the workbook. The Excel file gets replaced weekly. The Excel file and powerpoint are in the same folder. I don't know if this makes a difference, but this is also on Teams. Is there a way to update the links using a macro?

Excel File Name Sample: IT_ACT
Excel Sheet Names: A,B,C,D,E (none of them have spaces)
PPT File Name Sample: PR_SC

I understand a little VBA, but this is a little above me.

Comment: If the Excel content is truly linked and not embedded, it should update automatically as soon as you open the PPTX after updating the Excel file. Or at least it will when the files are stored locally. Linking to files on OneDrive/SharePoint/Teams seems to be a problem area, though.